# Replace part of a string in python multiple times but each replace increments a number in the string by 1

Tags: python, string

I am modifying html tags in a large html file by giving each tag a unique name with different numbers. So that a javascript function can reference those tags with the modified name. I want to use a replace-like python function to do this.

So I have a string where i have a variable, button_number_count, inside of it.

An example of what I mean:

```
button_number_count = 1;

htmlString = "<img class=\"hiddenCopy\" onclick=\"copyCodeButton("+str(button_number_count)+")\"src=\"../img/Log in.png\"/>";
```

But I want to do a replace function on a much bigger string where I replace a certain text field and while I am doing that I increment the number.

An example of what I would like:

```
content_with_replace = content_with_replace.replace_while_Incr('</pre></code>','</pre></code>'+"<img... %d ...>", button_number_count, number_of_replaces );
```

Obviously it would not be this exact syntax but have the functionality where I can change an internal variable on every iteration at a specified pattern like `%d`.

Do you guys know of any such function or technique. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain your necessity clearly and not with code

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I added a little blurb at the top as to what the necessity is for and the reason why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to do the replacing, you can pass a function as the second argument rather than a plain string. The function will receive a `match` object based on what the regex matched. You can then use some thinking like `itertools.count()` (or your own object) to produce increasing numbers.

For example:

```
import re
from itertools import count

button_number_count = 1;
htmlString = "this is sometext with more sometext and yet another sometext"

counter = count(button_number_count)

// replace sometext with sometext1, sometext2...
new_string = re.sub(r'sometext', lambda x: x.group(0) + str(next(counter)), htmlString )
```

The new_string will look like:

```
'this is sometext1 with more sometext2 and yet another sometext3'
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I wanted to print out the same count twice before iterating like str(next(counter)) + str(counter). The second would output `count(counterNumber)` is there a way so that it ignores the word count and just outputs the internal value.

Comment: The best I can do is `re.sub('count[(][0-9]+[)]',re.findall('[0-9]+',str(counter))[0],str(counter))` and just inline it where I would do `str(counter)`